# The content-type \"text/plain\" is not supported

Tags: symfony

i'm new to symfony, i followed a tutorial, i expect to create two groups of `put` and `post` `denormalizations`, i want the result of display on persist and not the same of update result, so i declare `"normalization_context "= {" groups "= {" get "}}` to control each operation, for update I choose fields which will modify and fields which will not change, like `username` and  `posts` and `comments`, I authenticate by `user` whose id = 74 and I want to modify this `user`, so I run `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/users/74`
and I send json data:

```
{
    "username": "najibupd1",
    "email":"najimard1@gmail.com",
    "name":"najib naj1",
    "password": "123456",
    "retypePassword": "123456",
}
```

in `postman` by the `PUT` method for update user but it gives me error `"The content-type \" text / plain \ "is not supported. Supported MIME types are \ "application / ld + json \", \ "application / json \", \ "text / html \". ",`.

**src/Entity/User.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiResource;
use App\Repository\UserRepository;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Annotation\Groups;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;

/**
 * @ApiResource(
 *  itemOperations={
 *       "GET"={
 *         "access_control"="is_granted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY')",
 *         "normalization_context"={"groups"={"get"}}
 *         },
 *         "PUT"={
 *          "access_control"="is_granted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY') and object == user",
 *          "denormalization_context"={
 *            "groups"={"put"},
 *            "normalization_context"={"groups"={"get"}}
 *          }
 *       }
 *   ,
 *  "DELETE"},
 *  collectionOperations={"GET","POST"={
    "denormalization_context"={
             "groups"={"post"}
           },
          "normalization_context"={"groups"={"get"}}
 }},
 *)
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=UserRepository::class)
 * @UniqueEntity("username")
 * @UniqueEntity("email")
 */
class User implements UserInterface
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @Groups({"get"})
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     * @Groups({"get","post"})
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     * @Assert\Regex(pattern="/^[a-z]+$/i", message="this field is not respect the pattern")
     * @Assert\Length(min=5, max=10, minMessage="ce champ doit avoir au moins {{ limit }} char",maxMessage="ce champ ne doit pas avoir plus de {{ limit }} char")
     */
    private $username;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     * @Groups({"post","put"})
     */
    private $password;

    /**
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     * @Assert\Expression(
     *   "this.getPassword() === this.getRetypePassword()",
     *   message="password does not match"
     *)
     * @Groups({"post","put"})
     */
    private $retypePassword;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     * @Groups({"get","put","post"})
     * @Assert\NotBlank(message="ce champs est obligatoire !")
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     * @Groups({"post","put"})
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     * @Assert\Email
     */
    private $email;
    
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Post", mappedBy="author")
     * @Groups({"get"})
     */
    private $posts;
     
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Comment", mappedBy="author")
     * @Groups({"get"})
     */ 
    private $comments;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->posts = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->comments = new ArrayCollection();
    }
```

Comment: probably a postman "problem", where you can probably set the content-type (of request and the accepted content type of the response). text/plain is really a rarely used (if ever) content-type in the web context (unless downloading plain text documents)

Comment: @Jakumi thx for u answer i edit my question

Comment: set Header content-type: Application / json in your postman request

Comment: @johnSmith thx for u answer but i dont know how ??

Comment: easy https://www.google.com/search?q=postman+set+header&oq=postman+set+header